# Convert *argv[] (command line parameters) to unsigned char vector

Tags: c++, vector, command-line, char, argv

In C++ I'm trying to convert command line *argv[] pointer (3 arguments) to vector of unsigned chars i.e. `mytest 148 64 127`

I got a vector:

```
vector<unsigned char> msg;
```

Vector includes 3 unsigned chars : `msg = {0, 0, 0}`
When I trying to convert in this way,

```
unsigned char c1 = *argv[1];
unsigned char c2 = *argv[2];
unsigned char c3 = *argv[3];
msg = {c1, c2, c3}
```

I get only first character of these chars.
i.e.
In command line I enter : `mytest 148 64 127`

I get : 1, 6 and 1

Comment: `unsigned char` is a single character not a string of characters so it makes sense.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args(argv+0, argv+argc);` is one usual way to start

Comment: It is unclcear what you are trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to convert those decimal numbers into the corresponding ASCII character (so 64 would be `'@'`)?

Comment: *"command line *argv[] pointer"* -- this is already a misunderstanding or a typo. Since you invoked the program with three arguments, `argv` is an  array of four pointers; is it not simply a single pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is convert to using strings.

```
vector<string> msg;
```

If you really want unsigned chars, then you will need to do something like:

```
vector<vector <unsigned char>> msg;
```

Rather than copy the characters you can save pointers to argv by doing

```
vector<unsigned char *> msg;
msg.push_back(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(argv[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a vector of strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        args.push_back({ argv[i] });
    }

    for (auto a: args) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are saving only the 1st `char` of each argument string into your `vector`.

```cpp
unsigned char c1 = *argv[1];
```

Is the same as doing:

```cpp
const char *str = argv[1];
unsigned char c1 = str[0]; // <-- 1st char only!
```

For what you are attempting, you need to instead *parse* each argument string as-is into the numeric value it represents, so that the argument strings `"148"` `"64"` `"127"` yield the integers `148` `64` `127`.  You can use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::stol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//#include <cstdlib>
//#include <limits>

/*
static const int min_uc = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min();
static const int max_uc = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max();
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        // no arguments given, do something...
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> msg;
    msg.reserve(argc-1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        int i = std::stoi(argv[i], nullptr, 0);
        //int i = std::strtol(argv[i], nullptr, 0);

        if ((i < 0) || (i > 255))
        //if ((i < min_uc) || (i > max_uc))
        {
            // bad input, do something...
            return 0;
        }

        msg.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(i));
    }

    // use msg as needed...

    ...
}
```